# Is there any way in Sharepoint to add a different form to each stage of a workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow, form

I am trying to figure out a a way to do the following in a workflow

- If in stage 1 => Send form1
- once form1 value1 is true Move to stage 2
- In stage 2, Send form2
- Once form2 is marked "complete"
- end Workflow

I am a beginner so please excuse if its unclear. We do not have infopath or visual studio in this org. I was told that it may be possible to do with tasks, but I am not certain on that.

thanks,

Comment: Like a collect data from user or start task process? Those would be 2 areas to start with.

Comment: right, both actually. how can I collect data using a form ( different forms for each stage? )

Comment: each of those actions has ways to configure different forms depending on what you want t do

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using content types.  You can also have the workflow automate the sending of the appropriate form/content type based on user inputs.  Below is a very basic example.  You can have the workflow toggle the content type for you or you can embed the content type in the URL link you provide in the email so that the form pulls up in that content type.

[image]

Note this only really accomplishes what you need if you want all the data in the same list/record.